# How to run a function from a sourced shell script (ex. node version manager, nvm.sh) in a task runner?

Tags: bash, shell

The task runner (see https://taskfile.dev/) is installed as a bin executable which runs shell command tasks specified in a .yaml file.

nvm is a node version manager written in a bash shell script ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

Since the script is sourced in .bashrc, typing `nvm ls` in the bash shell will run the nvm.sh script as expected.

But using `nvm ls` as a command in the yaml file, it indicates nvm cannot be found in $PATH.

Using `$(nvm ls)` in the yaml file yields the same result.

Using `source ~\.nvm\nvm.sh && nvm ls` in the yaml file, it seems to source nvm, but `nvm ls` doesn't appear to be executed.

So how to run a function from a sourced shell script (ex. node version manager, nvm.sh) in a task runner?

Comment: I would write a wrapper script, which sources nvm.sh and performs the necessary nvm operations, and invoke this wrapper from your yaml file. Alternatively, you could write a wrapper just around nvm.sh, which sources this file and based on its parameters invokes the respective function.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how _taskrunner_ is implemented, but intuitively, I would have expected that your approach would also work. For testing, I would have done a `set -x; source ~\.nvm\nvm.sh; nvm ls`, and analyze the stderr. BTW, you did not say what shell task runner is using. If task runner runs the tasks with POSIX shell, your approach can't work of course.